# Way to extract values in fluentd config from log line to use as output param value?

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to figure out if I can extract values from the record in an match config, and use those as values to config params.  Specifically using the amqp output plugin (https://github.com/giraffi/fluent-plugin-amqp).  In the example below, I am supposing I could extract a field, `job_id`, and use it as a value for the `exchange` param.  For host, I am supposing that I could take that same value and pass it as an argument to some embedded Ruby code.

```
<match sometag>
  @type amqp
  exchange record.job_id
  host "#{lookup_output_host(record.job_id)}"
  ... blah blah blah ...
</match>
```

An alternative way to get the job_id I need would be to extract it from the source file path, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Or do I pretty much need to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract value (job_id) from records?
fluent-plugin-amqp does not support extracting configuration value from records.
fluent-plugin-amqp sends records to the host that is defined in the configuration statically.

Comment: Ok, thanks, was hoping there was some magic way to do it.  If there's no way I can do it via a Ruby snippet, I guess I'll need to extend the amqp plugin.

Comment: There are no magic way to do it. You can extend fluent-plugin-amqp using `extract_placeholders`. See https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/api-plugin-output##extract_placeholders(str,-chunk)